# How to reset to git-svn remote "branch"?

Tags: git, git-svn

How can I reset my local Git branch to the `git-svn` remote "branch"?

In Git I can execute the command `git reset --hard origin/master` to reset my local `master` branch back to the `origin/master` remote branch.

How does this work if you use the Git-SVN bridge?

Comment: `git-svn` is not a bi-directional bridge between `git` and `svn`. It is not possible to create such thing because Subversion doesn't support most of the functionality provided by Git. The purpose of `git-svn` is to help the developers convert their existing codebases and workflows from Subversion to Git. It is uni-directional, for most of its functionality.

Comment: What does that mean: "git-svn is not a bi-directional bridge between git and svn."? I can do `git svn rebase` and I can do `git svn dcommit`. In the end Git should look in the SVN repository and set my local Git banch to same "revision". Why this should not be possible?

Comment: I mean not a full bi-directional bridge. It pushes commits from Git to Subversion but most of the Git concepts are not supported by Subversion. Even a fundamental concept as "branching" is handled differently by Git and Subversion. Subversion, f.e., creates a new commit when a branch is created. Git, on the other hand, thinks branches as pointers to commits. Branches are more flexible in Git while they are almost set in stone in Subversion.

Answer (score 2):

It makes no difference, you do it exatly the same.
Your local branches are just local Git commits on top of the `git-svn` produced commits.
You can at any time use normal Git `rebase`, `reset` and so on as long as you only modify local commits, none that were fetched from SVN.
On `dcommit` `git-svn` then looks for the first commit in the history that came from SVN and commits into the respective branch of that commit.